# Failure when pass param between functions in js

Tags: javascript, extjs, param

when i launch my applicattion appears the next failure: "record is null or is not an object", appears in the next line " var record = context.record;" Somebody could explain or find the failure... i try to pass the var "mola" from beforeedit to the edit function...

My code is the next:

```
listeners: {

        beforeedit: 

            function preditar(editor, e, eOpts, mola) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();

            dia = hoy.getDate(); 

            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }

            mes = hoy.getMonth();

            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);

            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            //alert(fecha_actual);

            var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            //alert(mola);
            editar(mola);

            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
                 }
                else{
                    e.cancel = true; //mo permite
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit:

         function editar(e, context, mola){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             var mola2= mola;
             alert(mola2);
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             //alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));

             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
});
```

Comment: You are calling function with single argument. editar(mola) so context and mola will be null inside the function

Comment: ok, i think that the problem is that, but how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Since there isn't any reference to 'context' then you might want to try and see if eOpts works or it could be 'grid'. I don't know, you will need to check out if these variables contain an object called 'record'. Use the browser's developer tools (F12) to check the values.

Comment: when i don have that function mi code works fine, then record have any value, i see in a alart, my problem really is to pass a var between functions in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function with

```
editar(mola);
```

But the function is defined as:

```
editar(e, context, mola)
```

So the function only receives the e parameter and the others are set to undefined.

Comment: i tried to use   var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
             //alert(mola);
             editar(e, context, mola); but appears the next failure "context is not defined"

Comment: any solution with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not the `mola` variable but `e.record`. As your error message states the variable `e` either does not contain an object `record` or `e.record` is `null`. Try to `console.log(e)` to inspect your variable `e` further.

Comment: when i tried this alert(JSON.stringify(recordData)); i obtein the correct information included in that field... i think that 555k is in the rigth way because if a quit the param mola in the two functions, my program run properly, but when i tried to pass the var between the two functions is when the failure apperas